# Objective C - Check if object in array is a dictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to set an image according to the value of the key in the dictionary. So I am not writing a bunch of if-else's I am trying to see if I can loop through the values in the array and see if it equals the key in the dictionary.

I have a dictionary:

```
    NSDictionary *dict=[gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.infTeam1 setText:[dict objectForKey:HOME_TEAM_NAME]];
    [cell.infTeam2 setText:[dict objectForKey:AWAY_TEAM_NAME]];
    NSArray *teams = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bucks",nil];

    for (NSString *team in teams) {
        if ([team isEqualToString:dict[@"homeTeamName"]]) {
            // add image
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on my teams array. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the actual code causing the error. Point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: my teams array is highlighted with the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Comment: Can you also post the stack trace of the Bad Access?

Comment: I think your var i is undefined at the beginning and it would be -xxxx or 22 or a mac address which your array[i] is not exists

Comment: @Horst I typed that in rather than copy/paste from xCode. I had it defined and updated the code.

Comment: @Raspu there is nothing helpful in the stack trace... xCode stops because of this error and the app tries to load the page

Comment: then just change it to for(NSDictionary *team in teams) to see if it's okay

Comment: Is [dict valueForKey:@"homeTeamName"] an array?  Does it respond to containsObject?  That would cause a crash, but the error would read "unrecognized selector sent to blah blah"

Comment: @danh dict is a NSDictionary.. I am trying to match keys to each value in my teams array.. I believe it responds to containsObject

Comment: Not referring to dict, rather to the object that you get when you send `[dict valueForKey:@"homeTeamName"]` (see @bensarz answer below).  That's the object that must respond to containsObject

Answer (score 0):

`[dict valueForKey:@"homeTeamName"]` returns a string, not an array there for a string does not have `containsObject:` available.

What you want is this:

```
for (NSString *team in teams) {
    if ([team isEqualToString:dict[@"homeTeamName"]]) {
        // the home team is part of teams
        // you might want to add a break statement to stop the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Simultaneous mind meld, but the error message casts doubt on this explanation.

Comment: There so much context missing. I provided an answer for what OP wants to do. Where `teams` is set or taken from could be another problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was typing... please provide more context. Where is `teams` instantiated, how and do you retain it?

Comment: Based on your recent edits, your array doesn't seem to be the problem. I'd dig more into that `NSDictionary *dict=[gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` that doesn't seem to be a dictionary. Good luck!